# What is a single word for "point(s) of personal information"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't recall if the word has a singular form. The plural form has a meaning closely analogous to "personal data" and my vague personal recollection is that it ends with an '*i*' or an '*a*'.

It is *not* a general word like 'miscellany', 'factoids', 'data', etc. It refers specifically and exclusively to bits of personal information such as name, age, favourite food, etc.

Any help jogging my memory would be much appreciated.

Example sentence:

> When it came time to introduce himself, James divulged only the basest [*word*]: his given name, his occupation, and the names of his dogs.

Comment: "Point of personal information" has a parliamentary meaning -- raising a question to inform the questioner.  Similar in use to "point of order" & more formally known as "point of inquiry".

Answer (score 1):

I would use "details" there:

> **detail** *n*
>   1. An individual part or item; a particular: *discussed the details of the proposal*
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/detail)</sub>

You could also use *items* or *particulars* as well, since they are synonyms.

> When it came time to introduce himself, James divulged only the barest details: his given name, his occupation, and the names of his dogs.

Note that I changed *basest* to *barest*. *Barest* suggests a minimum, *basest* suggests falling short in dignity or below standards, which doesn't sound like what you want.